# The data types nvarchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I am using the following cursor command to update a record on my table based on a join.

I have some similar code working fine in another part of my program, but without using LIKE logic on the join.

But when I execute the this code it throws an error.

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   The data types nvarchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @tablevalue NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX); 

DECLARE table_value_cursor CURSOR 
FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT [Tariff Lookup]
    FROM [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325];

OPEN table_value_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM table_value_cursor INTO @tablevalue 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT @sql = N'

   UPDATE [masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325] 
   SET [masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[Sell Price] = 
ROUND ([Orbisrates].[dbo].[Orbis_Import_June2014].[Peakperminute] / 60 * [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[ChargedTimeSecs] + [Orbisrates].[dbo].[Orbis_Import_June2014].[Peakconnect], 4) 
   FROM [OrbisRates].[dbo].[Orbis_Import_June2014]
   INNER JOIN [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325] on [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[To] LIKE [Orbis_Import_June2014].[Destination]+'%'
   WHERE 
      [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[tariff lookup] = '''+ @tablevalue +'''';

   EXEC sp_executesql @sql; 

   FETCH NEXT FROM table_value_cursor INTO @tablevalue; 
END 

CLOSE table_value_cursor 
DEALLOCATE table_value_cursor;
```

PS. I have tested the update section in the middle and that runs fine on its own.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because of wrong use `LIKE` operator as in below statement from your code

```
INNER JOIN [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325] 
on  LIKE [Orbis_Import_June2014].[Destination]+'%' <-- Here
```

Just put it inside quote. You should do something like below (a sample example)

```
select * from table1
where order_id like '%''' + order_no + '%'''
```

So in your case you should change it as below

```
   SELECT @sql = N'
   <....Rest Of Code ...> 
   on [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[To] 
   LIKE' + '%''' + '[Orbis_Import_June2014].[Destination]' + '%''' +
   ' WHERE [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325] ...'
```

**EDIT:**

You don't need a cursor for what you are trying to do. What you are essentially doing is 
for each value of `[Tariff Lookup]` under table `[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325]` you are
trying to do the `UPDATE`. The same can be achieved simply by a single query; by means of making the 
selection of `[Tariff Lookup]` a subquery like below. give it a try and see how it goes.

```
UPDATE masked325 
SET masked325.[Sell Price] = ROUND (orbit14.[Peakperminute] / 60 * masked325.
[ChargedTimeSecs] + orbit14.[Peakconnect], 4) 
FROM [OrbisRates].[dbo].[Orbis_Import_June2014] orbit14
INNER JOIN [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325] masked325
on orbit14.[Destination] = masked325.[To]

WHERE masked325.[tariff lookup] 
IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Tariff Lookup]
    FROM [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325]
  );
```

Sidenote: The `WHERE` condition actually doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: Thanks @ Rahul, the query now runs successfully - but unfortunately with zero effected rows?

Comment: If I run the UPDATE query on its own (without the quotes) it affects. (3842 row(s)) The problem is when I wrap it in the cursor I get the error

Comment: @user3580480, that's a separate question which should have been posted separately. anyways, edited my answer. Check the `EDIT:` part.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul that's working now, marked as Answered

Comment: @user3580480, a +1 probably... ahh!! I am so greedy. LOL ... just kidding :). You are welcome.