# Dynamic SQL with LIKE condition

Tags: sql-server

I've tried a number of different combinations of the below code, but I keep getting the same error.

Previous solutions I've found, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596886/the-data-types-nvarchar-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-modulo-operator), didn't have the extra complexity of being embedded in dynamic SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
DECLARE @table as NVARCHAR(25) = 'proposals'
DECLARE @column as NVARCHAR(25) = 'daypart'
DECLARE @modulo as NVARCHAR(5) = ''%''

DECLARE @COL_SELECT AS NVARCHAR(2000)

SET @COL_SELECT = 'SELECT DISTINCT column_name 
                   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
                   WHERE table_name = ' + @table + '
                     AND column_name like ' + @modulo + @column + @modulo + ''

EXEC(@COL_SELECT)
```

Error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator.

Comment: Be careful here. This appears to be highly vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: For debugging dynamic sql like this you should use the PRINT command so you can see the dynamic sql before you run it. It will help solve a lot of issues with quotes in dynamic sql.

Comment: @SeanLange, very true! In this case it would have at least pointed to the fact, that the dynamic SQL was not even reached :-)

Comment: same thing happens here, if i use triple quotes, i get "Incorrect syntax near 'daypart'."

Comment: Why are you trying *triple* quotes?

Comment: @SeanLange Good call, when printing it, i realized that the cause of the incorrect syntax error when using single or triple quotes for the modulo was the fact that %daypart% is not wrapped in single quotes which it should be. Thus, in my original code i had double quotes. But how do i avoid the issue Shnugo mentioned in regards to the incorrect evaluation of an empty string?

Comment: I don't quite get the point of using the variable for modulo at all. Why not greatly simplify that? AND column_name like %' + @column + '%'

Comment: @SeanLange, might be, that one can control this from outside and set the variable to an empty string to perform an exact search... But true, it's a bit strange this way...

Comment: When you initialize `NVARCHAR(n)` variables, you should *always* use the `N` prefix to indicate this is a Unicode string: `DECLARE @column as NVARCHAR(25) = N'daypart'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should run well:

```
DECLARE @table as NVARCHAR(25) = 'proposals'
DECLARE @column as NVARCHAR(25) = 'daypart'
DECLARE @modulo as NVARCHAR(5) = '%'

DECLARE @COL_SELECT AS NVARCHAR(2000)
SET @COL_SELECT = '
SELECT DISTINCT column_name 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = ''' + @table + '''
    AND column_name like ''' + @modulo + @column + @modulo + ''''

PRINT @COL_SELECT
EXEC (@COL_SELECT)
```

Print will give you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'proposals'
    AND column_name like '%daypart%'
```

This query should be executed without errors.

Comment: Wouldn't your definition of `LIKE` lead to something like `LIKE '%+daypart + %'`? Why the `+` symbols?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your PRINT-output... OK, but still: Why?

Comment: No it leads to `like '%'+'daypart'+'%'` indeed it is overkill, changed to `like '%daypart%'`

Answer (score 1):

The error happens here:

```
DECLARE @modulo as NVARCHAR(5) = ''%'';
```

This is interpreted as *Find the modulo value of two empty strings*

Use single quotes here...

### UPDATE Attention!

There's one more point: You will have to add doubled quotes for the table's name and *within* your `LIKE` to create a correct statement...

```
DECLARE @COL_SELECT AS NVARCHAR(2000)
SET @COL_SELECT = '
                    SELECT DISTINCT column_name 
                    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
                    WHERE table_name = ''' + @table + '''
                        AND column_name like ''' + @modulo + @column + @modulo + ''''
```

Comment: If i use singe quotes, i get "Incorrect syntax near 'daypart'."

Comment: the var @table needs triple quotes as well

Answer (score 1):

William

Use TWO quotes in @COL_SELECT, before and after @table and @modulo variables:

```
DECLARE @table as NVARCHAR(25) = 'proposals'
DECLARE @column as NVARCHAR(25) = 'daypart'
DECLARE @modulo as NVARCHAR(5) = '%'

DECLARE @COL_SELECT AS NVARCHAR(2000)
SET @COL_SELECT = '
    SELECT DISTINCT column_name 
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = ''' + @table + '''
    AND column_name like ''' + @modulo + @column + @modulo + ''''

EXEC(@COL_SELECT)
```

Hope it helps.
Ricardo